# Does Nicanor's account of Alexander survive?

Tags: identification-request, greek-language

I came across allusions to a source in one of the volumes of the Ante-Nicene Fathers, relevant summary by Oxford:

> The learned Roman scholar and antiquarian M. Terentius Varro decided
> to take matters in hand and sort out the jumble of Sibyls in a
> systematic manner in the mid-1st century BCE. Varro, as reported by
> the Church Father Lactantius in the 4th century CE, compiled a list of
> ten Sibyls, duly citing his source for each of them, and recording
> them in chronological sequence. His assiduous researches identified
> the first as coming from Persia and the second from Libya,
> interestingly enough, thus locating the earliest of them outside the
> Hellenic world, although his sources were themselves Greek—Nicanor,
> the historian of Alexander, and the tragedian Euripides.

(Primary source: https://st-takla.org/books/en/ecf/007/0070012.html)

Search engines don't seem to return anything related to this text. I get mostly [Nicanor Son of Parmenion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicanor_(son_of_Parmenion)). The [Nicanor disambiguation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicanor) also doesn't seem to list anyone that matches the time period as a historian or source. I'm led to think it's a lost source, but I can't confirm this.

### Question

Who is the Nicanor that Varro and Lactantius are referring to and does his account survive?

Comment: [It appears that](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Alexander_the_Great_in_the_Early_Christi/hnKyDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA162&printsec=frontcover) no one knows for sure...see [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Quintus_Curtius_his_history_of_the_wars/k4gDAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=RA2-PA26&printsec=frontcover) as well.